# return a function object with parameter binded?

Tags: python, function, object, return

All,

```
def a(p):
    return p+1

def b(func, p):
    return func(p)

b(a,10)   # 11
```

here I do not want the result "11" actually, what I want is a function object with the parameter has been binded, let's name it c.

when I use `c()` or something alike, it will give me the result 11, possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `functools` module provides the `partial` function which can give you curried functions:

```
import functools

def a(p):
    return p+1

def b(func, p):
    return functools.partial(func, p)

c = b(a,10)
print c() # >>  11
```

It can be used to apply some parameters to functions, and leave the rest to be supplied:

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

add2 = functools.partial(add, 2)
print add2(10)  # >> 12
```

Comment: can you explain why 2 and 10 can be separated?

Comment: functools.partial takes a function and some number of arguments, then returns a function that takes the rest of the arguments.

Comment: partial doesn't return a function but a partial object, so if you want to do f(c) with f expecting a function that will fail !

Answer (score 10):

you can also  use the functools module

```
import functools

def add(a,b):
    return a+b

>> add(4,6)

10
>> plus7=functools.partial(add,7)
>>plus7(9)
16
```

Answer (score 6):

The only way to do that, is to wrap it in a lambda:

```
c = lambda : b(a,10)
c() # 11
```

Though if you're going to name it anyway, that doesn't really buy you anything compared to

```
def c():
  b(a,10)
```

Comment: thanks, actually I will have a list of b(a,x), I want use [x() for x in list] to get the result in a go.

Answer (score 2):

Though I am not sure of the use, Use lambda:

```
>>> def a(p): return p+1
... 
>>> def b(func, p):
...     g = lambda p: func(p) 
...     return g
... 
>>> 
>>> b(a, 4)
<function <lambda> at 0x100430488>
>>> k = b(a, 4)
>>> k(5)
6
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `functool` and returning a function object work. A small test I ran showed that returning a function object method is slightly faster.

```
import time
import functools

#####################################
## Returning function object method
#####################################

def make_partial(n):
    def inc(x):
        return x+n
    return inc

start = time.clock()
for i in range(10000):
    g = make_partial(i)
print("time taken to create 10000: {}".format(time.clock() - start))

b = 0

start = time.clock()
for i in range(10000):
    b += g(i)
print("time taken to use it 10000 times: {}".format(time.clock() - start))


#####################################
## Using functools method 
#####################################

def make_partial2(x,n):
    return x + n

start = time.clock()
for i in range(10000):
    g = functools.partial(make_partial2,i)
print("time taken to create 10000: {}".format(time.clock() - start))

b = 0

start = time.clock()
for i in range(10000):
    b += g(i)
print("time taken to use it 10000 times: {}".format(time.clock() - start))
```

Which resulted in:

```
time taken to create 10000: 0.0038569999999999993
time taken to use it 10000 times: 0.0030769999999999964
time taken to create 10000: 0.004314000000000151
time taken to use it 10000 times: 0.00390299999999999
```

Showing it's both faster to make and call. (Albeit not by much)

Answer (score 0):

You can create another function that calls the your function with the parameter that you want.

```
def old_function(x,y):
    return x+y

def bound_parameter_function(x):
    return old_function(x,10)
```

Of course, if you need to create such functions on the fly, you can write another function that does the job for you:

```
def parameter_bound(f, parm_to_bind):
    def ret(y):
        return f(parm_to_bind,y)
     return ret

new_func=parameter_bound(old_function,10)
new_func(1)
```